# can ping google dns, but not google.de -> unknown host // worked in another network

Tags: debian, networking, dns, resolv.conf

I have a Laptop with Debian Jessie installed. At my home network, I could connect successfully to the internet (`ping google.de` successful). At the external network, I can't ping google.de (result: unknown host google.de), although I can ping 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (those are [the Google public DNS servers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39072))

I assume `/etc/resolv.conf` was configured to use a private DNS resolver(nameserver 255.0.0.0) at home, therefore it doesn't work at the external network.  Changing that to nameserver 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as suggested in [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39072) doesn't help, it is overwritten after the `dhclient` is run. `chmod -w /etc/resolv.conf` (it has now only read permissions) also doesn't help. It is still overwritten when running `dhclient`.

I use `ifup` and `ifdown` and those legacy tools to connect.

My `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid <...>
    wpa-psk <...>
</code>
```

**Now my question:**

> You need to make sure DHCP (if in use) is configured correctly, and
> your local DHCP server (usually your cable / adsl modem) is handing
> out the right details.

How do I do that? I can't use [this suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39417), because obviously I have no internet connection.

Comment: Did you use NetworkManager? which dhcpclient?

Comment: i do not use NetworkManager (although i want to install in in the future). I use dhclient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have setup your network device(s) with DHCP change the `/etc/resolv.conf` file manually, the file will only be overwritten when `dhclient` is restarted and not constantly. When you changed the `/etc/resolv.conf` file you should be able to perform hostname lookups and to be able to install the `resolvconf` package. After the package is installed you can follow the instructions in the referenced question [debian, problem with DNS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39071/debian-problem-with-dns/39417#39417) to finish your's.

Comment: That debian dns answer is wrong.  you install `resolvconf`if you want `/etc/resolv.conf` to be automatically managed (by dhcp, pon, etc).  You purge it if you want such things to leave your `/etc/resolv.conf` alone.

Comment: @cas well, im not sure if i understood your answer. But `dhclient` obviously doesn't leave my /etc/resolv.conf alone, but when i follow the installation and configuration of `resolvconf` /etc/resolv.conf doesn't becomes replaced just completed with the private dns

Answer (score 1):

You can enter in the configuration of the dhcp client (dhclient.conf) :

> prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;

this should overwrite the information passed from the server DHCP

Comment: I haven't tried that possible solution, because the one suggested by @Lambert works perfectly. Anyways thanks :)